# Signalr error on namechange

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr, jscript

So I just started off trying to work with Signalr for a project I'm working on. I have fairly little experience with JScript or Jquery, but a decent amount of experience with C#

I made the tutorial project on microsoft docs for a chat app [over here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

So this is probably a fairly dumb question in the eyes of most.

in the script I replaced

```
chat.server.Send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
```

with

```
chat.server.GetServerName($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
```

and in the hub added the function

```
public void GetServerName(string name, string message)
{
    // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
}
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: chat.server.GetServerName is not a function

If all the rest of the project is identical, how does this happen?

My apologies if this is a duplicate, I've been looking for almost 5 hours with no sensible answer to my question elsewhere that I'm aware of.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution, maybe the changes in your hub havent been picked up yet

Comment: probably you may need to lowercase **G** in chat.server.getServerName($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());.

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa yes, I faintly remember there being an issue with casing while testing my signalR app a while back. Good spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you need to start the method name in lowercase when calling from SignalR client

```
chat.server.getServerName($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
```

Replace **GetServerName** with **getServerName**

Answer (score 0):

Use invoke method of the Hub to call server methods from the client:

```
yourHub.Invoke("GetServerName", $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
```